# Does GroupIntoBatches guarantee that code is run only once per batch?

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, beam

Reading this article https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/after-lambda-exactly-once-processing-in-google-cloud-dataflow-part-1

The side effects section says

> Cloud Dataflow does not guarantee that this code is run only once per record, whether by the streaming or batch runner. It might run a given record through a user transform multiple times, or it might even run the same record simultaneously on multiple workers; this is necessary to guarantee at-least once processing in the face of worker failures

If I use the [GroupIntoBatches](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/transforms/java/aggregation/groupintobatches/) transform will the resulting batch be run through a user transform multiple times?